# Can Laravel Spark be used without Stripe or Braintree

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I want to create a SaaS application. Therefore I want to use Laravel Spark as base, but in my country the payment solutions (Stripe or Braintree) aren't widely accepted. Is it possible to use Spark without the suggested payment solutions?

My application will mail every month an invoice to the customers for their subscription. The customers pay the invoices by a simple wire transfer. Is this doable with Laravel Spark?

Comment: The sources are closed, right? And the FAQ says that it's just these two. So I'd say no. But you could contact Mr. Otwell ...

Comment: It's doable. Are you wanting Spark to detect the wire transfer, though?

Comment: No I don't need a detecting by Spark. I will do this in my accounting software.

Comment: Then yes you could use Spark if you wanted to, you just wouldn't be touching the payments side of things at all - as you are doing this manually.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a go

Answer (score 4):

There was a lot of discussion very early on for Cashier when it was strictly Stripe around support for other gateways (notably PayPal) - see [this closed github issue](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/7), including a [comment from Taylor](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/7#issuecomment-144710860) that he's happy for people to write Cashier-compatible gateway extensions.

This has been asked for varying gateways [again](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-cashier-implementing-different-payment-gateways),
 and [again](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-2checkout), and [again](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/29)... and [again](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/283).

Later Taylor added [Braintree (PayPal) support for Cashier](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-braintree) and [there was much rejoicing](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/702919087089852416?lang=en). There are a few differences between Stripe and Braintree which are noted in the Spark documentation and are generally limitations of the services rather than the library itself being unable to make them completely interchangeable.

There [has been talk](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/add-new-payment-method-in-spark/replies/307477) of people extending Cashier/Spark with more gateway types, but no guides/OSS contributions as yet (that I could find). There are certainly some *Laravel* packages out there for other gateway types (like [Paymill](https://packagist.org/packages/threesquared/laravel-paymill) or [2checkout](https://github.com/arleslie/2checkout)), but these aren't the same thing as being *Cashier* compatible (and thus more easily dropped into Spark).

You could certainly change the code yourself to *remove* the gateway payment elements if you wanted to only use it for invoicing and handle payments completely separately (via confirming wire transfers on your bank statements, etc.) but again, there isn't an out-of-the-box solution for it.